# Pyserial processing data from microcontroller

Tags: pyserial

I am new to Pyserial, I'm trying to use it for communication between my computer and a microcontroller, I need to receive the data and put it into variables so that I can plot with those variables. Is there any way to do this? I have currently figured out reading data from input signals.

```
import serial
import sys
import Queue
import threading

ser = serial.Serial(port='COM6',timeout=None, baudrate= 57600)

# opening the port 'ser' that was just created to receive data

flag = ser.isOpen()

print flag

while 1:

    data = ser.read(1)

    n = ser.inWaiting()

    if n:

        data = data + ser.read(n)

    data = data.split()


    for item in data:

        item = str(item)

        sys.stdout.write(item + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing it like the following: to transfer data to and fro my AVR and Beagle running UBuntu.

serial = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyO1", baudrate=9600)

then after opening the serial port at a particualr set baudrate you just need to:

```
while True:
     while serial.inWaiting() > 0:
           inChar = serial.read() # Read a character inChar has that byte what is sent over the UART
```

and to send over to the microcontroller just do serial.write("") that's it.
but make sure while you do all these commands the serial line is open()

Comment: Yes I can now read the data from microcontroller as the way I want, but I am still trying to figure out how to assign those data into variables so that I can plot them because it is a real time system.

Comment: Can you please be clear by what you mean by assign those values to variables .you already do that here >> inChar =serial.read () where in the incoming bytes get assigned to the variable inChar.

Comment: Oh..ok..my bad. I mean currently I can see these data displayed, but I can't put them into matlab to do plotting, is there a way to manipulate the data that I read? Thanks

Comment: Manipulate data to what form? Do you want to manipulate data to a specific form and plot it on matlab?

Comment: Yes, I'm sending coordinates, so it will be 1,2,3,4,5,6... and in matlab it will plot (1,2,3) and (4,5,6) in 3D space